# MonoDroid use Beta, MonoTouch use Release?

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin.android

We have enterprise licenses for both MonoDroid and MonoTouch from Xamarin.

Our MonoTouch is production so we can't install Beta versions, but we are learning/testing MonoDroid and wish to install the Beta version.

How can we have this configuration when the update channel in MonoDevelop allows for only 1 mode (Release/Beta/Alpha)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch between channels, and you do not have to install everything MonoDevelop offers you. This means that you can:

- Switch to stable channel and install MonoTouch updates (and ignore anything else)
- Switch to beta channel and install Mono for Android updates (and ignore anything else)

This is of course not optimal, since MonoDevelop will not offer updates for the channel you don't currently have selected, and you'll also be offered updates you may not want. The first problem can be solved by switching channels periodically (for instance once a week).